# Entity Framework duplicate items when inserting entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these 2 classes

```
public class xABaseObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Objekt")]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Beskrivning")]
    public string ObjectDescription { get; set; }
    
    [DisplayName("ObjectType")]
    public ObjectType objectType { get; set; }

}

  public class ObjectType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Namn")]       
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<xABaseObject> xABaseObjects { get; set; }
}
```

when i insert a new xABaseObject, and try to get ObjectType to attach to xABaseObject.ObjectType, it creates a new item in the ObjectType table with the same name.
how can i associate the existing ObjectType to the new xABaseObject without creating new ObjectTypes.

Here is the code to insert

```
 foreach (XmlElement xAObject in xAobjects.ChildNodes)
                {                       
                           string ExistingObjectTypeName = XMLExtraction.GetObjectType(xAObject);
                            xAbaseObject newObject= new xAbaseObject
                            {
                                ObjectName = "Name",
                                ObjectDescription = "objectDescription",                                                                       
                            };
                        newObject.objectType = db.ObjectTypes.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name="ExistingObjectTypeName");
                                                                   
                    db.xabaseObjects.Add(newObject);
                    db.SaveChanges();                     
                }
```

Comment: When you call the Insert method in EF, it automatically inserts the child entities, so you don't have to  insert it manually, you should do this when you;re updating, Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is a far less error-prone way to assign objects by their ID. Especially with detached objects you will save yourself a lot of headache.

Expose the foreign key in your model:

```
    [DisplayName("ObjectType")]
    public virtual ObjectType objectType { get; set; }

    public int ObjectTypeId { get; set; }
```

Assign by setting the ID, instead of the object.

```
obj.objectType = null;
obj.ObjectTypeId = idOfObject;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in

Answer (score 0):

I hope the line below is just a typo in what you've posted an not your actual code.

```cs
newObject.objectType = db.ObjectTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "ExistingObjectTypeName");
```

The equality check should be double equals sign. I'm not sure what an assignment would do within the FirstOrDefault.

```cs
(x => x.Name == "ExistingObjectTypeName")
```

Comment: its missing,  this is not the solution !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, another thought. Is it as simple as the order of your adding the newObject to the db context and setting the objectType property?

Try changing them to the below order:

```cs
  db.xabaseObjects.Add(newObject);
  newObject.objectType = db.ObjectTypes.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name="ExistingObjectTypeName");
```

While, as José Polanco, the save changes inserts child objects, like you I always thought that was only if they didn't exist.

As you've selected an existing object I feel it should be possible to add the relationship without needing to change the ObjecTypeId from being a shadow propery.